# How to use many emails and configure dsn

Tags: symfony, symfony4, mailer

I'm using symfony4.3 and I'd like to know how can I use many emails in my application. Actualy I have configured just one email (no-reply@my_domain.com) and it wokrs fine but I'd like to add some others emails such (contact@my_domain.com , administration@my_domain.com ..).

```
#.env
MAILER_DSN=smtp://no-reply@s****.com:password@smtp.s***.com
```

mailer.yaml

```
 #mailer.yaml    
 framework:
 mailer:
    dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
```

and this is an example how to send email:

```
    $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
    ->from(new NamedAddress('no-reply@s***.com', 'SiteName'))
    ->to($to);
    // rest of code
    $this->mailer->send($email);
```

**EDIT:**
I found this topic https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/33409 ,I think I must wait until **November** when symfony 4.4 be released

Comment: There's a section on using multiple mailers here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html Maybe that will help you. You should then be able to use each mailer like `$this->mailer_x->send($email)`

Comment: That's for SwiftMailerBundle , I'm using symfony mailer. I found this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/33409 ,I think I must wait until November when symfony 4.4 be released